# DownloadManager.remove(download_id) crash app

Tags: android

I am trying to cancel downloading task with id.

I get id from

```
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadId = manager.enqueue(req);
```

I want to stop download when on user button click, but I tested to stop download after 10% of being downloaded in this test code.

the code "manager.remove(downloadId);" is working perfect to clear downloading noti and stopping the task with requested ID. But it also stop the app too, app error also occur after that code. please how can I solve the problem.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
boolean downloading = true;

while (downloading) {
DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
q.setFilterById(downloadId);
cursor = manager.query(q);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
final int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
    downloading = false;
}

final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);
String finalDl_size;
int dl_size = (int) (bytes_total/(1024*1024));
finalDl_size = Integer.toString(dl_size)+" MB";
if(dl_size>1000){dl_size=(int) (bytes_total/(1024*1024*1024));
finalDl_size = Integer.toString(dl_size)+" GB";}


final String finalDl_size1 = finalDl_size;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
      btndownload.setText("Downloading "+Integer.toString(dl_progress)+"% , "+ finalDl_size1);
      if(dl_progress==100){
         btndownload.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
         btndownload.setText("Download Completed");
      }
      else if(dl_progress>10){
         try{
               manager.remove(downloadId); ///// Stop after 10%
            }
         catch (Exception e){}
       }
    }
    });

  cursor.close();
  }
  }
}).start();
```

Logcat Output

[image]

Please Kindly help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
               manager.remove(downloadId); ///// Stop after 10%
```